# why use of as nickname route using in laravel and when use it

Tags: laravel, as-keyword

advantage of `as keyword` using laravel route system

```
why, when and where its usage is better
```

how many ways to access route url define by the as keyword and without define as keyword in laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using named routes lets you change the URL for your routes without having to go change the URLs all throughout the application. It's also potentially shorter - you can (as a contrived example) have a named route of `login` for the path `app/user/login`.